# Sequences and ordinary generating functions

Tags: combinatorics

Find the ordinary generating function of the sequence <1, -1, 1/2!, -1/3!, 1/4!, ...>. I feel that it's a combination of sin and cosine functions but not sure. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, what your thoughts on it are; this will stop people from saying things you already know and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic info about writing math at this site see 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ , 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238 , 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/ and 
http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1):

If the ordinary generating function of a sequence $a_n$ is $G(a_n; x_n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $, then the function you want is:

$\displaystyle G\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n!};x\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!}= e^{-x}$.